# Closing a popup-window with geb after an alert

Tags: selenium, testing, webdriver, geb

I'm trying to achieve the following using the Geb Testing Framework:

1. I've opened a popup-window
2. I click on a button
3. An alert is raised
4. After clicking ok the popup is closed. (which is my actual problem)

I'm using this code which raises a WindowNotFoundException:

```
// open the popup by clicking the link (javascript)
withNewWindow({ selectLink.click() }) {
    // doing some other stuff in the opened window

    // closing the window by clicking a button
    // Javascript will close the window after the alert is closed
    withAlert {                    // <- The error is raised here
        $(".select").click()
    }
}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: Window not found. The browser window may have been closed.
Command duration or timeout: 15 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b1534ae328c771e0856c93e187490ca824', time: '2016-03-15 10:43:46'
System info: host: 'dev1b', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.16.0-4-amd64', java.version: '1.8.0_92'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=true, rotatable=false, handlesAlerts=true, databaseEnabled=true, version=45.7.0, platform=LINUX, nativeEvents=false, acceptSslCerts=true, webStorageEnabled=true, locationContextEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: 9b775683-e9c9-4651-a5fd-2c1f5e9fcb91

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:701)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.getPageSource(RemoteWebDriver.java:511)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MethodMetaProperty$GetBeanMethodMetaProperty.getProperty(MethodMetaProperty.java:76)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.GetEffectivePojoPropertySite.getProperty(GetEffectivePojoPropertySite.java:64)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:296)
    at geb.report.PageSourceReporter.getPageSource(PageSourceReporter.groovy:42)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:210)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:59)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:166)
    at geb.report.PageSourceReporter.writePageSource(PageSourceReporter.groovy:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:210)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:59)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:174)
    at geb.report.PageSourceReporter.writeReport(PageSourceReporter.groovy:29)
    at geb.report.Reporter$writeReport.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at geb.report.CompositeReporter.writeReport(CompositeReporter.groovy:31)
    at geb.report.Reporter$writeReport.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at geb.Browser.report(Browser.groovy:927)
    at geb.Browser$report$8.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at geb.junit4.GebReportingTest.report(GebReportingTest.groovy:37)
    at geb.junit4.GebReportingTest.writeGebReport(GebReportingTest.groovy:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:33)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatchman$1.evaluate(TestWatchman.java:53)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:55)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:237)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: Window not found. The browser window may have been closed.
Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b1534ae328c771e0856c93e187490ca824', time: '2016-03-15 10:43:46'
System info: host: 'dev1b', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.16.0-4-amd64', java.version: '1.8.0_92'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at <anonymous class>.nsCommandProcessor.prototype.execute(file:///tmp/anonymous1889291378920456774webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12719)
    at <anonymous class>.Dispatcher.executeAs/<(file:///tmp/anonymous1889291378920456774webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:9558)
    at <anonymous class>.Resource.prototype.handle(file:///tmp/anonymous1889291378920456774webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:9705)
    at <anonymous class>.Dispatcher.prototype.dispatch(file:///tmp/anonymous1889291378920456774webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:9652)
    at <anonymous class>.WebDriverServer/<.handle(file:///tmp/anonymous1889291378920456774webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:12517)
    at <anonymous class>.createHandlerFunc/<(file:///tmp/anonymous1889291378920456774webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/httpd.js:2054)
    at <anonymous class>.ServerHandler.prototype.handleResponse(file:///tmp/anonymous1889291378920456774webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/httpd.js:2387)
    at <anonymous class>.Connection.prototype.process(file:///tmp/anonymous1889291378920456774webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/httpd.js:1223)
    at <anonymous class>.RequestReader.prototype._handleResponse(file:///tmp/anonymous1889291378920456774webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/httpd.js:1677)
    at <anonymous class>.RequestReader.prototype._processBody(file:///tmp/anonymous1889291378920456774webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/httpd.js:1525)
    at <anonymous class>.RequestReader.prototype.onInputStreamReady(file:///tmp/anonymous1889291378920456774webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/httpd.js:1393)
```

The problem is that I want to close the window. There is some data shared between the popup and the parent window and after selecting the right value in the popup this window should close.

I already tried to catch the exception. But then I would need to tell Geb to use the right window (the parent window which is still open).

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm still looking for a solution... Anybody has an idea?

Answer (score 2):

By default Geb closes the window opened via a `withNewWindow()` call at the end of the execution of that method. You can ask it not to do so using the [`close` option](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/#code-close-code-2):

```
withNewWindow({ selectLink.click() }, close: false) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hey erdi. Thanks for your reply. I already tried that but I'm still getting the same error at the withAlert line.

Answer (score 0):

So if i read that right, your clicking OK on the alert, then you get the error.

Sounds like Geb doesn't know what page it's on and you need to wrap your code with a waitFor:

```
waitFor {
        withWindow({ isAt MyPage}) { true }
    }
```

Comment: Hey Rushby. Thanks for your reply. I think that's the point: Geb doesn't know on what page it's on. 

Can you clarify which part of my code I should wrap? Are you checking for the parent window or for the popup window? I tried to wrap the whole withNewWindow but I think you might meant something else..?